# Xcode 11 beta 7 (11M392r) incompatible with Catalina beta 7 (19A546d)?

Tags: xcode11

I'm getting `dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI11ButtonStyleP4body13configuration9isPressed4BodyQzAA0C0VyAA0cD5LabelVG_SbtFTq` when trying to run my Catalyst app with both Xcode 11 and Catalina on beta 7 where yesterday it ran just fine on beta 6. Of course, I already cleared `DerivedData`. Does someone has a solution for this I didn't try yet or can confirm that Apple just messed up here?

Comment: Same problem: dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI7BindingVyxGSlAASMRzSH5IndexRpzlMc